# Create dataframe from dictionary of list with variable length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary of list which is like -

```
from collections import defaultdict
defaultdict(list,
            {'row1': ['Affinity'],
             'row2': ['Ahmc',
              'Garfield',
              'Medical Center'],
             'row3': ['Alamance','Macbeth'],
             'row4': [],
             'row5': ['Mayday']})
```

I want to convert this to a data frame.
The output should look like-

```
ID  SYN1    SYN2    SYN3    SYN4    SYN5
row1    Affinity                
row2    Ahmc    Garfield    Medical Center      
row3    Alamance    Macbeth         
row4                    
row5    Mayday
```

Comment: Can you explain what "variable length of the values is varying" means?

Comment: hear 'row 2' contains 3 values..while 'row1' has just 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`collections.defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`.

So you can just use [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient='index')
res.columns = [f'SYN{i+1}' for i in res]

print(res)

          SYN1      SYN2            SYN3
row1  Affinity      None            None
row2      Ahmc  Garfield  Medical Center
row3  Alamance   Macbeth            None
row4      None      None            None
row5    Mayday      None            None
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can using `Series`

```
df=pd.Series(d).apply(pd.Series).fillna('')
Out[55]: 
             0         1               2
row1  Affinity                          
row2      Ahmc  Garfield  Medical Center
row3  Alamance   Macbeth                
row4                                    
row5    Mayday
```

Or from dataframe constructor

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=list(d.values()),index=d.keys())
Out[64]: 
             0         1               2
row1  Affinity      None            None
row2      Ahmc  Garfield  Medical Center
row3  Alamance   Macbeth            None
row4      None      None            None
row5    Mayday      None            None
```

Then we create the column

```
df.columns='SYN'+(df.columns+1).astype(str)
df
Out[67]: 
          SYN1      SYN2            SYN3
row1  Affinity      None            None
row2      Ahmc  Garfield  Medical Center
row3  Alamance   Macbeth            None
row4      None      None            None
row5    Mayday      None            None
```