# Creating a dataframe from dictionary with arbitrary length values (using recycled keys as column value)

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I am struggling with converting a dictionary into a dataframe.

There are already a lot of answers showing how to do it in the "wide format" like https://stackoverflow.com/a/52819186/6912069 but I would like to do something different, preferably not using loops.

Consider the following example:

I have a dictionary like this one

```
d_test = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3]}
```

and I'd like to get a dataframe like

```
index id    values
0     A     1
1     A     2
2     B     3
```

The index can be a normal consecutive integer column. By recycling I mean turning `'A'=[1, 2]` into two rows having `A` in the id column and the values in the values column. This way I would have a "long format" dataframe of the dictionary items.

It seems to be a very basic thing to do, but I was wondering if there is an elegant pythonic way to achieve this. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 2 lists. One from the keys, and other one from the values of the dictionary. As you defined the lists you can pass the lists into the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
dic = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3], 'D': [4, 5, 6]}

keys = []
values = []

for key, value in dic.items():
    for v in value:
        keys.append(key)
        values.append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'id': keys,
     'values': values,
    })
print(df)
```